# MathNet.Numerics crashes with 'segmentation fault' when trying to switch to Intel MKL

Tags: intel-mkl, math.net

I'm getting a

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

error when I try to run the following code under Linux:

```
// Using the Intel MKL native provider
MathNet.Numerics.Providers.LinearAlgebra.LinearAlgebraControl.UseNativeMKL();

var w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var y2 = m.Solve(v);
Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed);
Console.WriteLine(y2);
```

My setup:

- MathNet.Numerics: 4.15
- MathNet.Numerics.MKL.Linux-x64: 2.0.0
- intel-mkl package 2020.0.166-1 installed using `apt-get install intel-mkl`

My project uses Net Core 3.1. I use dotnet command to compile. My system is Ubuntu version 20.04.3 LTS